# Return the IP address each binding resolves to in IIS

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis, iis-8.5

I am working on getting a script together that will tell me every binding on a server and what live IPv4 address that binding resolves to. I am very close, but because I am exporting my results from IIS to CSV and then running Test-connection on each binding from that CSV, I'm having trouble adding the results to an array and exporting the finished results to a CSV file. Here is the script:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
$hostname = hostname
$Websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
$date = (Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')
foreach ($Site in $Websites) {
    $Binding = $Site.bindings
    [string]$BindingInfo = $Binding.Collection
    [string[]]$Bindings = $BindingInfo.Split(" ")#[0]
    $n = 1
    $i = 0
    $status = $site.state
    $path = $site.PhysicalPath
    $fullName = $site.name
    $state = ($site.name -split "-")[0]
    $Collection = ($site.name -split "-")[1]
    $status = $site.State
    $anon = get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/AnonymousAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath IIS:\sites -Location $site.name | select-object Value
    $basic = get-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/BasicAuthentication -Name Enabled -PSPath IIS:\ -location $site.name | select-object Value
    Do{
        if( $Bindings[($i)] -notlike "sslFlags=*"){
            [string[]]$Bindings2 = $Bindings[($i+1)].Split(":")
            $obj = New-Object PSObject
            $obj | Add-Member Date $Date
            $obj | Add-Member Host $hostname
            $obj | Add-Member State $state
            $obj | Add-Member Collection $Collection
            $obj | Add-Member SiteName $Site.name
            $obj | Add-Member SiteID $site.id
            $obj | Add-member Path $site.physicalPath
            $obj | Add-Member Protocol $Bindings[($i)]
            $obj | Add-Member Port $Bindings2[1]
            $obj | Add-Member Header $Bindings2[2]
            #$obj | Add-member ResolveAddress $result
            $obj | export-csv "c:\temp\$date-$hostname.csv" -Append -notypeinformation
            $i=$i+2
        }
        else{$i=$i+1}
    } while ($i -lt ($bindings.count))
}

$CSVvar = import-csv "c:\temp\$date-$hostname.csv"
$i=0
foreach ($v in $CSVvar){
If ($v.Header -ne '') {
$result = Test-Connection $v.Header -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($result) {
    $IP = ($result.IPV4Address).IPAddressToString
    echo $IP
    $v.ResolveAddress = $IP
}
}
}
$CSVvar | export-csv "c:\temp\$date-$hostname.csv" -Append -notypeinformation
```

I am thinking it would be best to ping each binding before the CSV file is exported the first time, but I can't figure out a way to get it to try each element of the Header object individually, and I keep crashing the script that way. If I can get the IP address(es) to save back to the $CSVvar.ResolveAddress column, that would be fine by me. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: A site binding can have no IP address at all (all unassigned for example). So your script makes many assumptions that you didn’t reveal as part of the question. Unless you edit it to include such, it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a lot of code, just to do this. How about this approach.

```
### Get website info

Import-Module -Name WebAdministration
Get-Website | select name,id,state,physicalpath,
@{n="Host"; e= { $env:COMPUTERNAME }},
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ';' }},
@{n="LogFile";e={ $_.logfile | select -expa directory}}, 
@{n="attributes"; e={($_.attributes | % { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';' }}, 
@{n="ConnectionTest"; e={(Test-Connection -ComputerName ($Bindings -split 'http |:')[1] -Count 1 -Quiet)}} | 
Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path 'C:\temp\my_list.csv'

Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\my_list.csv'

# Results

name           : Default Web Site
id             : 1
state          : Started
physicalPath   : %SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot
Host           : IIS01
Bindings       : http *:80:;https *:443: sslFlags=0
LogFile        : %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
attributes     : name=Default Web Site;id=1;serverAutoStart=True;state=1
ConnectionTest : True

name           : kcd
id             : 2
state          : Started
physicalPath   : C:\inetpub\kcd
Host           : IIS01
Bindings       : http 192.168.7.11:80:kcd.contoso.com
LogFile        : %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
attributes     : name=kcd;id=2;serverAutoStart=True;state=1
ConnectionTest : True
```

Of course one could break out / cherry pick all the other collected pieces / info into separate calculated properties as needed.

***Update for OP***

> ... but really all I'm having trouble with is getting the IPv4 info from
>   the ConnectionTest response appended to the original document ...

Just use the same code I used for the Test-Connection.

```
Import-Module -Name WebAdministration
Get-Website | select name,id,state,physicalpath,
@{n="Host"; e= { $env:COMPUTERNAME }},
@{n="Bindings"; e= { ($_.bindings | select -expa collection) -join ';' }},
@{n="LogFile";e={ $_.logfile | select -expa directory}}, 
@{n="attributes"; e={($_.attributes | % { $_.name + "=" + $_.value }) -join ';' }}, 
@{n="ConnectionTest"; e={(Test-Connection -ComputerName ($Bindings -split 'http |:')[1] -Count 1 -Quiet)}},
@{n="SiteIPA"; e={($Bindings -split 'http |:')[1]}}
```

Comment: Thanks, and yes your method does look more elegant. Perhaps I gave too much context, but really all I'm having trouble with is getting the IPv4 info from the ConnectionTest response appended to the original document the corresponding binding came from, a la: 

`#foo.csv 
google.com` 
Code Executes...
`$CSVvar | export-csv -Path 'bar.csv' -Append -notypeinformation
import-csv -Path 'bar.csv'
#Results
Name: google.com
IPv4: 172.217.15.110`

Comment: But the IPA associated with the binding is in the bindings field. Why would you want to try and get it again from the Test-Connection results? You can just pull that from the bindings field as I did for that Test-Connection call. See my update for you.

Comment: Because this is a maintenance script, helping to determine sites that do not in actuality have their domain pointed to this server any longer, so that the site can be removed. It doesn't really matter what I want to do with it though, What I need is the IP address that the binding actually resolves to. If it's a match for what is in IIS, awesome. If it is not, the site can be booted. Interrogating as to the why is not helpful. My question is clear, and the solution is still not.